# Is there any small animal that can jump over a meter high/long?

Tags: zoology, arthropod, bio-mechanics, locomotion, amphibians

By small, let's say less than 5 cm body length. I always thought that grasshoppers were the highest absolute jumpers in this class but the highest jump according to [this](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20160825-the-greatest-jumper-on-earth-is-probably-not-a-flea) article is 0.7 m...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no animal smaller than 5 cm can jump higher than 1 meter. grasshoppers and locusts have wings which supposedly disqualifies them. https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/highest-jump-by-an-insect.

The immense mechanical power that would be required for any animal to jump so high with such a small size is unbelievably high which is why they have developed different evolutionary adaptations. not to mention that the terminal velocity of such a small creature is very low so a jump would quickly become a fall due to the air molecules slowing them down. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7KSfjv4Oq0